# Not able to send JSON post data through http post to asms web servie

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, http-post, asmx

I am trying to send a JSON data to a asp.net web service(asmx) from angualrjs.
My angularjs code is below

```
 $scope.editdata = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/admin/Product.asxm/EditProduct',
            headers: {
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            data: JSON.stringify($scope.product)
        }).then(function (success) {
            alert("User updated successfully!");
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Error: User not updated!");
        });
    };
```

On the code behind file of the asmx webservice I have a method EditProduct

```
    [WebMethod]
    //public string EditProduct(string name, string code, int id)//working
    public string EditProduct(Product product)// not working
    {
        return "On the server side";
    }
```

Now my problem is if I remove the comment and receive the json as individual variable it is working fine, but when I am using the class to receive the json it is giving the below message

```
    ExceptionType=System.InvalidOperationException
    Message=Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'product'.
```

The product class is below

```
    public class Product 
    {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is in this $scope.product

Comment: it must be $scope.product={id:"data",name:"data",code:"data"}

Comment: $scope.product already has the required json, which I want to send to the server.

Comment: JSON.stringify({product:$scope.product})

Comment: Awesome.!.. This worked. Thanks @Shubham

Comment: no issue....enjoyy